# expo app gets stuck on splash screen when a received notification is clicked ,(background mode)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, notifications, expo

when my expo app (react-native) is not in the foreground (removed completely by swiping up) and I click on the received notification, the app opens and gets stuck on the splash screen .

platform : android.

I have no idea what can be the reason, has this happened to anyone?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This started happening for me after upgrading to Expo SDK 45. This only happens if the app not started at all. If the app is running, but in the background, tapping the notification launches the app no problem. Not seeing this issue on iOS at all.